# Mautic cannot save anything

Tags: zend-framework2, mautic

I've installed Mautic on my web server. There was no error. But when I try to save configuration or save new made page Mautic display that it is working something but there is no finish.

`Please wait...`

I do not know what is going on. Please help me! Thank you!
P.S. Because there is no mautic tag I have to use zend-framework!

Answer (score 2):

Same problem was solved for me by giving proper permissions to the files.

```
cd /var/www/mautic

find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;

chmod -R g+w app/cache/

chmod -R g+w app/logs/

chmod -R g+w app/config/

chmod -R g+w media/files/

chmod -R g+w media/images/

chmod -R g+w translations/

chown -R $USER:www-data .
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your issue is caused by the filesystem permissions. But to be sure, check Mautic logs in the /app/logs directory and the server error log as well.

BTW, Mautic is build on Symfony2 framework so it would be probably a better tag.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the most common issues you will find in the Mautic forums. And the problem is, if you are facing this there is not one but one of many reasons this could have happened. Like FrankS101 said it can be a permission issue.

I would recommend opening the log files inside the Mautc app directory and viewing the error logs generated by `vim app/logs/mautic_prod-DATE.log` and checking out what the error is to use the solutions provided below.

- You will have to set the owner of the entire Mautic directory to the owner of the running HTTP server instance, for example, Nginx service should have **nginx** or **www-data** as user group you have to check it out which one it is.
- If you are using apache, check the write permissions of apache to the folder especially these two folders `bundles` `logs`.
- You can also try increasing your PHP allocated memory inside the php.ini file. Do it wisely though it will depend on the amount of memory the server already has and how much you want to allocate to it.
- You can try disabling some plugins that you might have installed recently that could be causing conflicts.
- You can try clearing the cache and reload, this one can help too. remove the cache by `rm -rf app/cache/`

This can be the result of a faulty installation, and you might have to reinstall to update the database, so follow the installation [procedures](https://pepipost.com/tutorials/tag/mautic/) properly in order to get a bug free Mautic installation.